# How to create a css pie chart with three equal slices?

Tags: css

I am relatively new to css, and wondering what the easiest way would be to create a pie chart with three equal slices. I have been trying to work with [this codepen](https://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/hkxGp), but I don't really understand how they are using gradients and haven't been able to adjust it to my needs. Any help appreciated!

```
.rainbow-wheel {
  position: relative;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border: solid 2em white;
  width: 16em; height: 16em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(36deg, #272b66 42.34%, transparent 42.34%) 0 0,
    linear-gradient(72deg, #2d559f 75.48%, transparent 75.48%) 0 0,
    linear-gradient(-36deg, #9ac147 42.34%, transparent 42.34%) 100% 0,
    linear-gradient(-72deg, #639b47 75.48%, transparent 75.48%) 100% 0, 
    linear-gradient(36deg, transparent 57.66%, #e1e23b 57.66%) 100% 100%,
    linear-gradient(72deg, transparent 24.52%, #f7941e 24.52%) 100% 100%,
    linear-gradient(-36deg, transparent 57.66%, #662a6c 57.66%) 0 100%,
    linear-gradient(-72deg, transparent 24.52%, #9a1d34 24.52%) 0 100%, 
    #43a1cd linear-gradient(#ba3e2e, #ba3e2e) 50% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 50% 50%;
  transition: 1s;
}
```

Comment: Visit : https://cssgradient.io here you can visually generate CSS Gradient, and also able to get its css code, By studying it, you will be able to understand, how css gradient works and what other options are available.

Comment: any feedback from a comment or an answer is appreciated that it answers or not your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work from the example and remove a few of the gradient that you do not need, then update angle and start/stop values and finally update the background-color too:

```css
body { background: gainsboro; } 
.rainbow-wheel {
  position: relative;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border: solid 2em white;
  width: 16em; height: 16em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(60deg, #272b66 63.34%, transparent 63.34%) 0 0,
    linear-gradient(72deg, transparent 24.52%, #e1e23b 24.52%) 100% 100%,
    linear-gradient(-36deg, transparent 57.66%, #272b66 57.66%) 0 100%,
    linear-gradient(-60deg, transparent 36.52%, #272b66 36.52%) 0 100%, 
    #9ac147 linear-gradient(#e1e23b,#e1e23b) 50% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 50% 50%;
  transition: 1s;
}
/* hover ,click -> to check center is at center */
.rainbow-wheel:hover {transform:rotate(120deg);}
.rainbow-wheel:focus {transform:rotate(240deg);}
```

```html
<div class='rainbow-wheel' tabindex="0"></div>
```

When you do not understand some CSS code, you can remove the rules/values (or part of them here for the gradient) to find out what is the effect.